# Opening Sublime Text from Bash on WSL

Tags: bash, window, sublimetext3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have done

> alias subl='"/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"'

However, doing subl test.txt will now open Sublime text in C:/System32/test.txt, which doesn't exist and thus I can't save it. Nor do I want to save something to System32. How can I change it so that my actual files are opened?

Also, if I do subl ~/test.txt then it tries to open `C:\home\<myname>\test`.

Answer (score 6):

The first answer is good, but won't work if your linux fs is linking to a windows folder (i.e. `/home/me/something -> /mnt/c/something`  -  `subl ~/something/file` will fail), nor will it if trying to access the windows fs directly (i.e. `subl /mnt/d/file`).

Here's a more complete script I just wrote starting from the above answers, that will open files in sublime both on Windows or Linux paths.

https://github.com/grigger/subl-wsl

I know it's quite a while after the answer, but maybe some other folks will be helped by this in the future.

Comment: The use of `wslpath` really put me on the right track. Perhaps more details about it in the main answer instead of a link to a script?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a script that opens subl in the correct location and put it in your Linux `PATH`(e.g. in `/bin`).

That script opens `subl.exe` at the right location. For WSL1 the script could look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe "C:/Users/<Username>/AppData/Local/Packages/<WSL Distro name>/LocalState/rootfs/$*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a small alias to get this working:

```bash
subl() {
  DISTRO="Ubuntu"
  SUBLIME_TEXT_LOCATION="/mnt/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe"
  FILE=$1
  FULL_PATH=$(readlink -f $FILE)
  $SUBLIME_TEXT_LOCATION "/\/\wsl.localhost\\${DISTRO}${FULL_PATH}"
}
```

so typing

```bash
subl cghs-2023-02-28.log
```

would open the file in Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score -1):

WSL is like a Linux virtual machine for windows.
So you have to install sublime Text for Linux on WSL.

see [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html)

Comment: WSL is a compatibility layer, not a VM.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I think, you would need to set up a X-Server on your host and a GUI on WSL for this to work...